# How to populate the options value in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to solve a weird bug that is on select element. For some reason, there is always one black option on the top of the dropdown.

I have something like this in html.

this element is included in my test controller.

```
<select ng-model="vm.pickTest">
  <option ng-repeat="test in vm.tests"
          ng-selected="test.id === vm.pickTest.id">{{test.title}}</option>
</select>
```

inside test controller

```
   //init controller codes...
     vm.pickTest = {'id':'id1', 'title':'title1'}

     vm.tests = [
       {'id':'id1','title':'title 1'},
       {'id':'id2','title':'title 2'},
       {'id':'id3','title':'title 3'},
     ]
```

so when the page first loads, it will pre-select `'title 1`' by default. For some reason, I can see a blank option in my dropdown like:

```
(blank)
title 1 <---pre-selected
title 2
title 3
```

I have tried using

```
<select ng-model="vm.pickTest">
  <option value="" style="display: none;">test</option>
  <option ng-repeat="test in vm.tests"
          ng-selected="test.id === vm.pickTest.id">{{test.title}}</option>
</select>
```

as other posts suggested but still no lucks. I also don't want to use `ng-option` because of other restrictions in my codes. Can anyone help me to solve this issue? It's really annoying. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `ng-options` is the logical answer that i'm sure will solve your problem.  What are the other restrictions in your code preventing you from using it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-options` instead. Here's the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with @aup and @Brad. It is best to use  [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

But if you do have a restrict on the use of `ng-option`, you can use the following trick.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/8x0prgfc/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.tests = [{
      'id': 'id1',
      'title': 'title 1'
    }, {
      'id': 'id2',
      'title': 'title 2'
    }, {
      'id': 'id3',
      'title': 'title 3'
    }, ];
    vm.pickTest = vm.tests[0];
  })
  .directive('convertToObject', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope:{
     convertToObject:"="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        for(var i=0;i<scope.convertToObject.length;i++)
        {
          if(scope.convertToObject[i].id===val)
            return scope.convertToObject[i];
        }
        return null;
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
        return val.id;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <select ng-model="vm.pickTest" convert-to-object="vm.tests">
      <option ng-repeat="test in vm.tests" value="{{test.id}}">{{test.title}}</option>
    </select>
    <pre>{{vm.pickTest|json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

More about [$parsers and $formatters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).